Does "*some of the town council*" mean the same as "*some of the **members** of the town council*"?
This is a part of the book "Too Kill a Mocking Bird" by Harper Lee.
"Boo’s transition from the basement to back home was nebulous in Jem’s memory.
Miss Stephanie Crawford said some of the town council told Mr. Radley that if he
didn’t take Boo back, Boo would die of mold from the damp. Besides, Boo could
not live forever on the bounty of the county."
Does "some of the town council" mean the same as "some of the members of the town council"?
I don't really know what else this could mean, but I wouldn't say e.g. "Some of the band" when talking about "some members of a band", unless ofc, you can say that. I'm not a native speaker so I permit this possibility.
Some regulation research below:
town council
noun
(especially in the UK) the elected governing body in a municipality.

You certainly can say 'some of the band'. It is completely normal to talk about groups of people, animals, or things that way.

This works because the town council (and a band) is a group of people. It might not work in some other context in which "some of" applied to multiple kinds of things.

This is normal English.
Some takes this meaning (near the last few pages):
PRONOUN
6.
certain persons, individuals, instances, etc., not specified
Some think he is dead
Similar constructions with some of the council
can be found here.
Yes, some of the town council can also be understood here to mean some of the members of the town council or just some
members of the town council.
Elided in the respective versions are of the members and members.
Here some is a quantifier in the former and a determiner in the latter.

I would add that this is normal English and "some of the band" from the OP is just as normal. Some of the class stayed late to study.

Thanks, @Peter Kirkpatrick.  Agreed.  I've added the first sentence.
